# Trialforce Template and unmanaged code/package

Tags: lightning-aura-components, managed-package, unmanaged-package, trialforce

We are creating a Trialforce Template on Trialforce org and we would like to include below items in Trialforce Template.

1. One managed package which passed security review
2. One unmanaged package, which contains only reports/dashboards
3. One unmanaged (without package) Lightning component and a static resource, to show different logo based on the customers.

Can someone confirm if it is possible to add #2 and #3 into the Trialforce template?

Thanks.